# Object is not getting saved while using django non-rel

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-nonrel

My models.py :

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    projectName =models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True,db_index=True)
    projectManager = models.ForeignKey('Users')

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length =100 )
    team = ListField(models.CharField(max_length =100),null=True)
```

Now I am trying creating a Projects class object with this code in shell:

```
user_object = Users.objects.get(name="abc")

p = Projects(projectName="xyz",projectManager = user_object)
p.save()
```

On p.save() it gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 543, in save_base
    for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 876, in get_db_prep_save
    connection=connection)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 276, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 271, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/home/aprainfo/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.5.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 479, in get_prep_value
    return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4f1116115fcff377b2000001'
```

I dont know why its trying to convert string into int in last line.I dont know how to get rid of this error?

Comment: I am using mongoDB for storing data with django-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely with the installation of django non-rel and mongodb-engine. Standard django expects all ids to be integers whereas the suite of packages that make up django non-rel change that to allow the string-based id that mongodb uses.

I would suggest reinstalling your set up following the order defined on http://django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html

I had this same issue and it was a matter of the installation possibly using the standard django instead of the non-rel one.

My pip requirements.txt has these entries:

```
git+git://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine.git@master
git+git://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel.git@master
git+git://github.com/django-nonrel/django-permission-backend-nonrel.git@master
```

And then I would be able to do: `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`

Comment: also make sure to pip uninstall (regular) django, I had forgotten to remove it before installing django-nonrel and was having the same problem